# How to pass data across pages in Ionic?

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic-framework, mobile

I have an `Ionic` app that has usual User Login and Registration pages where I collect user's information such name, email, password etc. and store it in `DB`.

Once the user logs in I have some 2-3 pages where I ask the user to setup some basic data. 
Once the data setup is completed by the user I take the user to the Home page.
On the Home page there is an icon, clicking on which the user is taken to the `Account Settings` page where I fetch all the data that the user entered during registration such as name, email, address etc. after fetching it from DB.

The problem is that I am not sure how to carry or store the email address, that the user entered while login, across all these pages and use it 
in the `UserProvider/UserService` where the actual query can be executed such as:

```
select * from user where email='john@abc.com';
```

You certainly can do it using the `navParams` in `Ionic` and pass it across all the pages until it gets used on the final page but that doesn't look like the correct solution to me.

Since I come from `Java` background and I have used `session` object to pass data across web pages I am sure there must be something equivalent here which I am not aware of.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way to handle your situation is to create a service file and use that service file across your component.

service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class userService {
 userEmail: string;

 get() {
return this.userEmail;
 }
}
```

in your registration page, you can assign userEmail value like

```
export classRegistartion {
  name:string;


  constructor(private _userService: userService, private router: Router) {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

 reistrer(): void {
    // Code to navigate to the other component
    this._userService.userEmail = //email ngmodel;
  }
}
```

and in another component, you can retrieve the userEmail value just calling get() in your component.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the idea @Hrishikesh. Let me try this out